# LOD expression with multiple filters

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a calculated field to bring in the sum of sales where my category is fixed on a dimension but still be able to apply other filters (date, location) etc.

My data is set up like this:

Dimensions:

- categories (pants, shirts, shoes)
- location
- date

Measures:

- Sales
- Tax

I'm trying to output a column that only shows my sales for pants, and have the filters applied accordingly.
For some reason, my output:

My current view is to have date, location, and measure values as my columns, then categories as my rows.  If I select multiple locations/dates in my filters, it'll just aggregate based on the selected filters.

`{fixed [categories]='pants' : sum(sales)}` isn't outputting the correct number

Comment: Hello and welcome! We are lacking: the language you're using to submit your request, the request itself you are doing, and few of the results you have.

Comment: That code line isn't SQL.